# Why does my laptop slow down after a few minutes when i'm playing a game?

Tags: windows-7, dell-inspiron, overheating, gaming

I have a Dell Inspiron N5110 with a 2.5 Ghz Processor with Turbo Boost and a 1 GB dedicated graphics card and 4 GB RAM running Windows 7 Home Premium. Recently, when I play Skyrim and other games, I've noticed that the game slows down (jerks) after a few minutes of play. Why has this stared happening? This is not the way it was when I got the system.

Is there anything I can do to change this. Will getting more RAM help?

Dell support made me clean the TEMP folder etc. But things are still the same.

Someone else suggested I install a program that flushes the memory after a few seconds. Would this help? What are these programs that flush the memory?

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Do you have Anti-Virus? disable it then try! And do you check your PC with CCleaner Software ?

Comment: Yes I have a AV running when I play games.

Comment: Try to disable it and check your PC with CCleaner or Wise Cleaner software and feedback here.

Comment: Actually it's been running fine after I turned off the AV :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

His Problem Solved after He turned the Anti-Virus OFF.
Have FUN :)

Answer (score 4):

Of-course anything you are advised will be speculation, but one likely suspect is that your CPU (or GPU) is getting too hot, and is then slowing itself down so it can cool down - slower a CPU works, the cooler it gets - and most, if not all new CPU's have thermal protection.

You can check this theory by blowing a fan on the laptop and making sure there is good airflow around it and see if it takes longer to overheat.   There are also tools you can download to monitor the performance of the CPU and how hot it is.

Comment: Well, it does get really really hot.

Answer (score 2):

It's is frequently that a overheat protection works.

Try to look into Window Event Log

look under Application and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Kernel-Power\Thermal-Operational.

and see if there anything about passive cooling.

Comment: There's nothing about passive cooling. I've posted an image.

Comment: I saw you turn off the AV and problems seems fade away, but the root cause seems to be your AV overrun your CPU then it became hot and being throttled by some other software. The event log did show that the CPU was throttled......

Answer (score 2):

Your Event Log indicates CPU throttling. It's likely another mechanism is throttling your processor that is unknown to Windows.

Regardless, it looks like a heat issue. There are a number of things you can do to mitigate heat issues with laptops:

- Use your laptop on a flat surface, possibly raised up a little in the back
- Place the laptop on a cooling device, where the laptop is both raised up and has active cooling under it
- [Clean your laptop's cooling fans](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2021499/how-to-clean-your-laptops-cooling-fans.html) (somewhat risky)

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://www.2dayblog.com/2008/11/29/laptop-cooler-with-hdd-slot/)</sup>